# BinaryReader or Writer.Close() is not closing properly C#

Tags: c#, filestream, binaryreader, binarywriter

I have a form application that performs a simulation and constantly reads/writes a binary file. Everything works fine if you let it run through. However, if the form is closed/ the simulation is aborted the file-stream is not closed properly - leaving the file locked.
Is there a way to make sure all streams closed? I tried the following - but it has no effect...
Thanks a lot in advance,
T

```
        public BinaryWriter BinWrite;
        public BinaryReader BinRead;

        public BinaryWriter EnvBinWrite;
        public BinaryReader EnvBinRead;       

public void theForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            //Close all binary file reader/writers -- crashes if it cannot overwrite files
            foreach (Building B in AllBldgs)
            {
                try
                {
                    EnvBinRead.Close();
                }
                catch
                { continue; }
                try
                {
                    EnvBinWrite.Close();
                }
                catch
                { continue; }
                try
                {
                    BinRead.Close();
                }
                catch
                { continue; }

                try
                {
                    BinWrite.Close();
                }
                catch
                { continue; }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do any exceptions occur?

Comment: No, because you eat them all. Remove the try..catch blocks and see if any occur.

Comment: Ah ok... sorry Im new to coding - I used the try catch because the Reader and Writer are not always initialized ... will try without the try catch - thanks for your reply

Comment: Check if they are initialized before closing them... Try/catch should be used as a last resort and not a fix-all solution

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.  You have four streams, and you're trying to close each one inside of a completely unrelated loop -- (multiple times!) -- and meanwhile you're `continue`ing on catch, aborting all the rest of the closes. -- It is very unclear from this code what you're even trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you know what the `continue` keyword is for? Please note that this continues with the next *loop*, not the next *block of code*. So if an exception occurs closing `EnvBinRead`, you will *not* enter the block to close `EnvBinWrite`, but continue with the next item from `AllBldgs`.

To eat all exceptions and still try to close all the binary writers, you'd write:

```
foreach (Building B in AllBldgs)
{
    try
    {
        EnvBinRead.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Closing EnvBinRead failed!" + exp.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        EnvBinWrite.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Closing EnvBinWrite failed!" + exp.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        BinRead.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Closing BinRead failed!" + exp.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        BinWrite.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Closing BinWrite failed!" + exp.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please note that simply eating the exceptions is *never* a good idea. If you don't care whether the reader or write could be closed, check whether it has been initialized before closing it as suggested in the comments.

Comment: +1, since this is probably the source of the problem. Still, I'd advise that eating exceptions is a bad thing and that something like `if (BinRead != null) BinRead.Close();` would be preferable, if `BinRead` might be uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks! How can I check if an exception occurs?

Comment: using try catch, but saying continue means skip everything else and go straight to finally. in the catch block dont say continue, make it bring up a message box, saying there was an error or something

Comment: Erm - if an exception occurs, the `catch` block is executed. You could show a message or log the error using `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine`. I've edited my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: You should also remove the loop.  There's no reason for it here.  Unless you have a really custom implementation of `IEnumerable` that has side effects that occur when you iterate over it, I can't fathom why you would put that there. -- In some cases, it will never attempt to close any files, and in many others it will attempt to close them multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You should call dispose to close the BinaryReader and Writer.

**Explanation:**

`StreamReader, StreamWriter, BinaryReader and BinaryWriter` all close/dispose their underlying streams when you call Dispose on them. They don't dispose of the stream if the reader/writer is just garbage collected though - you should always dispose of the reader/writer, preferrably with a `using` statement. (In fact, none of these classes have finalizers, nor should they have.)

Personally I prefer to have a using statement for the stream as well. You can nest using statements without braces quite neatly:

```
using (Stream stream = ...)
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Whatever))
{
}
```

Even though the `using` statement for the stream is somewhat redundant (unless the `StreamReader` constructor throws an exception) I consider it best practice as then if you get rid of the `StreamReader` and just use the stream directly at a later date, you'll already have the right disposal semantics.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to use Using block for the streams, Closing them immediately after use.

Comment: Actually you don't really know. While the use of `using` is recommended when you actually want to close the stream right after reading/writing from/to it, there may be scenarios where the stream needs to be open over the application's entire lifetime. In that case, `using` can't be used at all.